# docx4j - NullPointerException in VariablePrepare.prepare()

Tags: office365, docx, docx4j

When I create a .docx using the online version of Office365, then my program crashes on the call to `VariablePrepare.prepare()`

Relevant code lines:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(docxFileContent);
WordprocessingMLPackage wordprocessingMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(inputStream);
VariablePrepare.prepare(wordprocessingMLPackage);
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.transform(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:271)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.filter(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:297)
    at org.docx4j.model.datastorage.migration.VariablePrepare.prepare(VariablePrepare.java:79)
```

My document created using Online Office 365: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MGZpsKZokmw6nyLbt_aAxsueUBl5tMnq/view?usp=sharing

Note that when you inspect the properties of this file, it is missing values for basic stuff like Pages, Word Count, Character Count, etc. See https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vvuf2zJvGqigX6SMVu-C6EMsYXu0378I/view?usp=sharing . If you open the document with a desktop version of office, then those values are suddenly populated and the crash no longer occurs. This issue is specific to documents sourced from Online Office 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now fixed at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/b877520c0a02804f00b2fce57d56405f045947f0

that bit of the code was assuming word/document.xml, which is incorrect for your document.

This fix will be in docx4j 6.1.0 (and in a nightly release sooner).

Comment: You are welcome, pls try now https://docx4java.org/docx4j/docx4j-nightly-20181129.jar

Comment: Thanks @JasonPlutext. Took me a little while to get back around to it, but I've just tried docx4j-6.1.0-release-candidate.jar and my problem has gone away. The fix is much appreciated, so thanks again. When can I expect the proper 6.1.0 release?